# Nmodbus4 check connection

Tags: c#, networking, client, modbus

This is a class for a client using Modbus/tcp Nmodbus4.
during a loop which calls the SendSingleInt method, I turn off the server and my application crashes because I could not check if connection exists. How to handle? Also, the client class is in a class library and it is not throwing exception to main program.

```
public class ModbusTCPClient
{
    private string ipAddress;
    private int tcpPort;
    public TcpClient tcpClient;
    private ModbusIpMaster clpMaster;

    public ModbusTCPClient(string ip, int port)
    {
        ipAddress = ip;
        tcpPort = port; // 502
        tcpClient = new TcpClient();

        try
        {
            
            tcpClient.BeginConnect(ipAddress, tcpPort, null, null);
            // Create modbus master device on the tcp client
            clpMaster = ModbusIpMaster.CreateIp(tcpClient);

            //TryConnect();

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            throw; //new Exception($"Não foi possível conectar o protocolo modbus no servidor {ip}.\r\n{err}");
        }

    }
    public void SendSingleInt(int intValue, byte deviceAddress = 1, byte valuePosition = 0)
    {

        if(clpMaster != null)
        {
            clpMaster.WriteSingleRegister(deviceAddress,  valuePosition, Convert.ToUInt16(intValue));
        }

        
    }
```

Comment: I am creating instance of the client, opening the connection and keeping alive.
Should I put it inside using block instead?
using(ModbusTcpClient clpClient = new ModbusTcpClient(ip, port)){ }

Comment: You just need an exception handler inside the SendSingleInt() method.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you can add the following code:

```
master.Transport.Retries = 1000;
master.Transport.ReadTimeout = 1000;
master.Transport.WriteTimeout = 1000;
serialPort.ReadTimeout                     
serialPort.WriteTimeout
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use try/catch before post this question but it was not work;
Later I realized that i was catching InvalidOperationExceptions and throwing just a new Exception() from my class! '¬¬